# Use Console Entries to Drive Class Presets

Tags: scripting

So above the ui in blender it shows a pulldown of all the operations performed while modelling. Is there any way to perform a bevel and then take the properties from the above bar and use that as a template for an operation.

[image]

The idea is to set up a bevel that can be repeated with the same parameters set by the user. Allowing equal bevelling. Maybe it would work better if there was a bevel that once done would set the preset for subsequent bevels.

Comment: Sure, you could copy that bpy.ops.mesh.bevel() line to the python console and execute it again. You would have to ensure that you're in edit mode with a mesh selected. You could also use a script to apply the bevel to multiple objects if you wanted. Let me know what you're looking for and I can try to narrow done the solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the `context.window_manager.operators` collection.  The property settings are in the `properties` collection.  `items(...)` returns a list of key, value pairs

```
setattr(op, key, value)
# a key value pair of ("width", 3)
#equivalent of
op.width = 3
```

Put this in a draw method and it will list all operators by name, and if it's a bevel op expand on the call method as seen in the INFO panel and list the key value pairs.

```
    box = layout.box()
    for o in context.window_manager.operators:
        row = box.row()
        row.label(text=o.name)
        if o.name == 'Bevel':
            bbox = box.box()
            row = bbox.row()
            row.label(text="bpy.ops.mesh.bevel(%s)" % ", "
                     .join(["%s=%s" % (k, str(v)) 
                            for k, v in o.properties.items()]))
            for k, v in o.properties.items():
                row = bbox.row()
                row.label(text="%s = %s" % (k, str(v)))
```

Here is a modal timer operator that captures the bevel operator properties once it becomes context.active_operator to do something while it is happening.
(Test Code)

Put your mesh into edit mode, then run the operator, the operator will cancel when the user leaves edit mode, this can be changed.

Whenever a bevel operator is used it saves the settings to a dictionary on the operator, and while a bevel operator is context.active_operator prints the settings to the system console.

```
import bpy


class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs its self from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

    _timer = None
    bevel_operators = {}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if context.mode != 'EDIT_MESH':
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'CANCELLED'}


        if event.type == 'TIMER':

            op = context.active_operator
            if op is None:
                return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

            if op.name == 'CSharpen':
                op.bevelwidth += 0.01
                if not op.run_modal:
                    #cancelled from CSharpen Operator update prop
                    self.cancel(context)
                    return {'CANCELLED'}

            elif op.name == "Bevel": # op.rna_type.identifier == "MESH_OT_bevel":
                key = hash(op)
                # save the operator props in a dictionary
                print("BEVEL", len(self.bevel_operators))
                print("bpy.ops.mesh.bevel(%s)" % " ,".join(["%s=%s" % (k, str(v)) for k, v in op.properties.items()]))   
                self.bevel_operators.setdefault(key, 
                                     {k:v for k,v in op.properties.items()})


        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.1, context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        print("Operator Cancelled")
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)
        # perform pre cancel here
        # print out the bevel operator dic

        for h, bo in self.bevel_operators.items():
            print(h, bo)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()
```

from code I set up from another answer to you where this operator talks to that operator "Csharpen"

Comment: I'll post the full code on BA that "talks" to Csharpen registerred op.

Comment: how about not having it connected to csharpen. I dont think the operator csharpen was supposed to have values piped into it. I meant more like a macro recorder for bevel that would allow it to be re-ran with the same values. Csharpen ideally was just supposed to collapse selected modifiers and run the sharpening operation and bevel it via modifier.

Comment: Then remove the   'if  op.name == 'CSharpen':` conditional block.  The code is in way of suggestion.  And yeah the modal timer is prob a bit OTT on one hand, ..

Comment: So what about the op being Bevel? So there isnt a way to retrieve the last operator of bevel in that area where it shows stuff like a callback or something?